# How to fetch key in the first line and next to next line in python dictionary

Tags: python

need some help in narrow down my issue.

here is the issue, i have one csv file which i have converted into dictonary.

csv format

```
switch1,10.222.197.8/29,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,a05-02,aad
ab14-app2-1-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.10,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,a05-02,aad
ab14-app2-3-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.11,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,a05-02,aad
ab14-cbatch2-1-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.12,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,a05-02,aad
switch2,10.222.197.24/29,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b05-02,aad
vl100--asw1-b05-02-aad.net.ddc.net,10.222.197.25,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b05-02,aad
ab14-app2-4-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.26,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b05-02,aad
ab14-app2-5-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.27,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b05-02,aad
switch3,10.222.197.0/29,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b09-02,aad
vl100--asw1-b09-02-aad.net.ddc.net,10.222.197.1,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b09-02,aad
ab14-app1-2-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.2,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b09-02,aad
ab14-app1-5-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.3,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b09-02,aad
ab14-cbatch1-1-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.4,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b09-02,aad
switch4,10.222.197.32/29,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b14-02,aad
vl100--asw1-b14-02-aad.net.ddc.net,10.222.197.33,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b14-02,aad
ab14-app2-2-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.34,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b14-02,aad
ab14-cbatch2-2-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.35,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,b14-02,aad
switch5,10.222.197.40/29,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,c12-02,aad
vl100--asw1-c12-02-aad.net.ddc.net,10.222.197.41,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,c12-02,aad
ab14-app1-1-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.42,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,c12-02,aad
ab14-dapp1-1-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.197.43,255.255.255.248,ab14-host_mini,100,c12-02,aad
vl112--asw1-a01-01-aad.net.ddc.net,10.222.250.241,255.255.255.248,aad-fdc,112,a01-01,aad
cs97-fdc2-20-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.250.242,255.255.255.248,aad-fdc,112,a01-01,aad
cs97-fdc2-22-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.250.243,255.255.255.248,aad-fdc,112,a01-01,aad
switch6,10.222.162.32/27,255.255.255.224,aad-fdc,101,a02-01,aad
vl101--asw1-a02-01-aad.net.ddc.net,10.222.162.33,255.255.255.224,aad-fdc,101,a02-01,aad
cs77-fdc2-9-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.162.62,255.255.255.224,aad-fdc,101,a02-01,aad
cs92-fdc2-2-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.162.34,255.255.255.224,aad-fdc,101,a02-01,aad
cs95-fdc2-2-aad.pps.ddc.net,10.222.162.35,255.255.255.224,aad-fdc,101,a02-01,aad
```

I have converted this into disctonary using below logic.

```
with open("pam.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        mydict = {rows[0]: rows[1] for rows in reader}
        print(mydict)
```

now i want to fetch the one of the switch name by giving the ip address , i have written the logic to get that but i am getting server name.

lets say example : i am trying to find the switch name when i give input in the below logic 10.222.197.4 but i am getting the server name called ab14-cbatch1-1-aad.pps.ddc.net.

how to fetch switch name for that server IP , so in my case i should get switch3

```
src = "10.222.197.4"


for key, value in mydict.items():
       
        if src in value:
            # key = mydict[src]
            print("found")
            print(key)
```

output: found

ab14-cbatch1-1-aad.pps.ddc.net

Comment: correction 

if src == value:

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more condition to match the switch name pattern:

```py
src = "10.222.197.4"
for key, value in mydict.items():
        if src in value and "switch" in key:
            # key = mydict[src]
            print("found")
            print(key)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , @zircoz i tried this but output is empty if I use src = "10.222.197.4 then I should get switch3 name

Comment: @shivram in that case while making dict, you should make the key as "switchx" and everything between that "switchx" and next "switchx" should be the value.

Answer (score 0):

Same basic idea as @Zircoz, but another approach would be to create a data structure optimized for your search cases in the first place:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
import re

switch_dict = {}
ip_pattern = r"(\d{1,3}\.?){4}"

with open("pam.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if "switch" in row[0]:
            ip_address = re.match(ip_pattern, row[1])[0]
            switch_dict[ip_address] = row[0]

pprint(switch_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'10.222.162.32': 'switch6',
 '10.222.197.0': 'switch3',
 '10.222.197.24': 'switch2',
 '10.222.197.32': 'switch4',
 '10.222.197.40': 'switch5',
 '10.222.197.8': 'switch1'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , @rthurwitz , i tried this but the output is i{'10.222.162.32': 'switch6',
 '10.222.197.0': 'switch3',
 '10.222.197.24': 'switch2',
 '10.222.197.32': 'switch4',
 '10.222.197.40': 'switch5',
 '10.222.197.8': 'switch1'}

but i want to get switch3 name  when I use src = "10.222.197.4 and for example if i use src = 10.222.197.34 then i should get switch4 name

Comment: @shivram, to clarify, in your data file does 10.222.197.0/29 mean all IP addresses between 10.222.197.0 and 10.222.197.29?